# C++ compare surf descriptors algorithm match breaks some times

Tags: c++, gcc, opencv, g++, surf

I wrote a c++ application that compares points matches from images (OpenSurf C++) but some times, 1 from some thousands of "getUniqueMatches", the application breaks in some point inside "getUniqueMatches". I has this log:

```
05/13/11 10:17:16: this->pointsA = 227
05/13/11 10:17:16: this->pointsB = 226
05/13/11 10:17:16: this->matches before = 0
05/13/11 10:17:16: 227 226 0 0.650000
05/13/11 10:17:16: Starting in getUniqueMatches

-- And here breaks, inside getUniqueMatches --
```

And this is the code:

```
inline bool findInVector(std::vector<int> v, int value) {
    int size = v.size();
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(v[i] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void getUniqueMatches(IpVec &ipts1, IpVec &ipts2, IpPairVec &matches, float ratio) {
    try {
        wLog(f("%d %d %d %f", ipts1.size(), ipts2.size(), matches.size(), ratio));

        float dist, d1, d2;
        Ipoint *match;

        matches.clear();

        std::vector<int> matched;

        wLog("Starting in getUniqueMatches");

        // Breaks after here

        int size = ipts1.size();
        int size2 =  ipts2.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            d1 = d2 = FLT_MAX;

            int foundJ = -1;

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
                dist = ipts1[i] - ipts2[j];

                if (dist < d1 && !findInVector(matched, j)) {
                    d2 = d1;
                    d1 = dist;
                    match = &ipts2[j];
                    foundJ = j;
                } else if (dist < d2) {
                    d2 = dist;
                }
            }

            if (d1 / d2 < ratio) {
                ipts1[i].dx = match->x - ipts1[i].x;
                ipts1[i].dy = match->y - ipts1[i].y;

                matches.push_back(std::make_pair(ipts1[i], *match));
                matched.push_back(foundJ);
            }
        }
    } catch(std::exception ex) {
        wLog(f("Exception in getUniqueMatches: ", ex.what()));
        return;
    }
}
```

Only some times breaks here. I don't know what is happening, maybe something wrong? The application uses only 1 thread when executing this function. When extracting points uses 10 threads.

Using it on Centos5 (VPS).
2 Gb RAm
20% hd used
Compiled using g++ (Performance mode), IDE used Netbeans.
OpenCV, libcurl.

Comment: Can't see anything obvious, have you tried more logging? As an aside I would use find in findInVector(), it uses iterators.

Comment: @Sasquiha, logging inside will be crazy, because not all time crashes inside and logging inside iterators will generate very big log files. Nothing obvious then?

Comment: it is possible the break is not in this function. What does the core file say?

Comment: @Sasquiha, breaks inside, there is a log after the call and only one thread. All times breaks there, inside the function.

Comment: @William, are you sure the buffer gets flushed? Again it is still possible that the log after the call does not come out. Does core file stack point to this function?

Comment: I was thinking about that, maybe not flushed because the 90% of the time points to that function, but the other 10% points to extrange characters... or repeats a line. So i tried to disable log but still fails. I will look some info about flushing to see where crashes, thanks. @Sasquiha

Comment: @Sasquiha, after writing to the file I make .flush to the stream, is breaking inside. I will try to add more logs inside. Where can I get the core file stack? When calling? Is not strerr right?

Comment: @Wiliam when you say the program breaks what do you mean? does a core file get generated, if so use gdb to have a look.

Comment: @Sasquiha, look at my other answer. Thanks

Comment: One advice (although it doesn't seem to be the problem here): accessing vector elements with the [] operator is tricky. In case of invalid index, you will crash... somewhere else, and you will search that error for hours. One idea is to use a macro, say VECTOR(v,idx), one version that will resolve to v.at(idx) in debug mode (with eventually a message printed in case of bad index), the other that resolves to v[idx] in release mode, to keep speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect 2 things:

- g++ compiler optimization. Use `-O2` or less; `-O3` and beyond sometimes generate weird behavior especially concerning floating point operation.
- If reducing optimization does not fix the problem, I suggest changing

  `if (d1 / d2 < ratio)`

  to

  `if (d1 < double(ratio)*d2)`

  for avoiding division by zero (unlikely happen I think) and for better precision result.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (d1 / d2 < ratio) {
```

for

```
if(d2 > 0 && ...) {
```

I think that the problem was a division by zero, but was not throwing exceptions. :(

Comment: Maybe because I writed "ex" and not "&ex" ? :(